# How to read array of json objects on MEAN Stack (with MySql instead of Mongo)

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

It happens that we are working on a web page that uses a list of users (for example) that we got from a MySql on the form of an array of JSON objects, it worked (we tested it with console.log() )... but that was until I activated Angularjs on the front-end.

The code that I used on the respective files are as follow...

controller.js (angular module):

```
var app = angular.module("App",[]);
app.controller("AppController",function($scope, $http){
    $scope.listofusers = [];

    $http.get('/api/users')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.listofusers = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log("Error: " + data);
        });
```

api.js:

```
router.route('/users')
    .get(function(request, response) {
        usuariosModel.getUsuarios(function(error, data) {
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            response.status(200).json(data);
        });
    })
    .post(function(request, response) {
        var datosUsuario = {
            username: request.body.username,
            password: request.body.password,
            email: request.body.email,
            permiso: request.body.permiso
        };
        usuariosModel.insertUsuario(datosUsuario, function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data) {
                response.status(200).json({
                    "Mensaje": "Insertado"
                });
            } else {
                response.status(500).json({
                    "Mensaje": "Error"
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/api/usuarios', function(req, res) {
    res.render('readusers.html');
    //res.sendFile(path.resolve('./views/readusers.html'));
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'readusers.html'));
});

app.get('/api/usuarios', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index_users')
});

app.put('/api/usuario/:username', function(req, res) {
    res.render('edit');
});



module.exports = app;
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require("./models/config.js");
var fs = require('fs'); // manejo filesync

var methodOverride = require("method-override");

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting: ' + error.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to server with thread ID ' + connection.threadId);
});

// DB structure
sql_structure = fs.readFileSync('./models/bd.sql').toString();

connection.query(sql_structure, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('Base de datos: Estructura completada');
});


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
//app.set("view engine", "html");
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use('/', require('./router/routes'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

//Express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//Routes
app.use('/api', require('./router/api'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server on");
});
```

Hope someone finds what is missing, we have looked through a lot of tutorials and still can't find the mistake.

Comment: What happened when you activated AngularJS?

Comment: If by activating AngularJS you mean putting the direction on a .html as script (like this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>), it happens that when we initialize the server, and run our controller to print the list of users, it prints a list of a lot of empty users.